# CSS Text align when wrapping

Tags: css

I'm having trouble aligning text when the window is resized, e.g. on mobile.
Here's the HTML:

```css
.count-panel {
  float: left;
  width: 64px;
  border: 1px #888 solid;
}

.count {
  font: 15px/18px Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.message {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='count-panel'>
      <span class='count'>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class='message'>This is line one</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='count-panel'>
      <span class='count'>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='message'>This is line two which is longer than the rest so it can test wrapping</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='count-panel'>
      <span class='count'>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class='message'>This is line three</div>
  </div>
```

At larger sizes: [Larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6h8o.jpg)

At smaller sizes: [Smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8uO2.jpg)

I need the text in the second line to align with the others and not wrap hard left as in the image. Thanks.

Comment: You can try giving the .message a line-height property with the height of the .count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just your `float: left` that's taking the count-panel out of sync.

I have replaced your example with `display: flex` instead. I would suggest avoiding float when positioning your elements as it was never intended to be used for layout. Flex is a much cleaner solution and I think it gives you more flexibility of layout choices. :-)

I've also amended the HTML layout slightly to include the border on the number itself so that it doesn't stretch the full size of the text content on smaller devices.

```css
.count {
  font: 42px Roboto, sans-serif;
  min-width: 64px;
  border: 1px #888 solid;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: max-content;
}

.message {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 10px 16px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='table'>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="count">1</span>
    <div class="message">This is line one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="count">2</span>
    <div class="message">This is line two which is longer than the rest so it can test wrapping</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="count">3</span>
    <div class="message">This is line three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour on mobile is due to the float applied to the `.count-panel` element. You could instead use flexbox and clean a bit the css code, like so:

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGKxdP)

```
.count-panel {
  border: 1px #888 solid;
  flex: 0 0 64px;

}

.count {
  font: 15px/18px Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.message {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  display: flex;
}
```